# Use Laravel route in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have a Laravel route returning a JSON, and I have a JS file that dynamically generates a table with the results in a JSON.
I just need to use this JSON in my JS table. That's all.

JS code (`registroCarros` should receive the value from the JSON, route or whatever)

```
function CreateTableFromJSON() {
    

    var registroCarros = []

    // EXTRAI VALOR PARA O HEADER HTML 
    var col = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < registroCarros.length; i++) {
          for (var key in registroCarros[i]) {
            if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                col.push(key);
            }
        }
    }

    // CREATE TABLE 
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    table.id = 'myTable';



   
    var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   //ROW.

    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
        var th = document.createElement("th");      //HEADER.
        th.innerHTML = col[i];
        tr.appendChild(th);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
       var td1 = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");      //HEADER.
       td1.id="teste;"
   }

    // ADD JSON IN TABLE AS ROWS.
    for (var i = 0; i < registroCarros.length; i++) {

        tr = table.insertRow(-1);

        for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
            var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
            tabCell.innerHTML = registroCarros[i][col[j]];
        }
    }

    
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);


    
}
```

My Controller (`dbtest` is a function in my model that have the SELECT im using):

```
 public function returnJSON()
    {
        $teste   = new user();
        return response()->json(($teste->dbtest()));
        
    }
```

and my route:

```
Route::get('returnJSON', 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller@returnJSON',           ['names' => 'returnJSON']);
```

all I need is to use this route in my JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ***Controller***

```javascript
public function returnJSON()
{
    $teste = new user();
    return response()->json($teste->dbtest());    
}
```

Then your ***Route*** should look like this:

```php
Route::get(
    'returnJSON',  // URL
    'App\Http\Controllers\Controller@returnJSON'  // Controller
)->name('returnJSON');  // Route name
```

Then finally in your ***blade*** file (JS code), you can use it as:

```javascript
// behind any event (e.g. button click or value change etc.)
fetch("{{ route('returnJSON') }}")       // This is the route name given in your route
// OR fetch("{{ url('returnJSON') }}")   // and this is the URL (either can be used)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => CreateTableFromJSON(data));

/* REMEMBER */
// Your "CreateTableFromJSON" function must require an argument
// so that it can take the response (returned JSON) in it    
function CreateTableFromJSON(registroCarros = []) {
    // EXTRAI VALOR PARA O HEADER HTML 
    var col = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < registroCarros.length; i++) {
        for (var key in registroCarros[i]) {
            if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                col.push(key);
            }
        }
    }

    // CREATE TABLE 
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    table.id = 'myTable';

    var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                          //ROW.

    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
        var th = document.createElement("th");             //HEADER.
        th.innerHTML = col[i];
        tr.appendChild(th);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var td1 = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");        //HEADER.
    td1.id="teste;"
    }

    // ADD JSON IN TABLE AS ROWS.
    for (var i = 0; i < registroCarros.length; i++) {

        tr = table.insertRow(-1);

        for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
            var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
            tabCell.innerHTML = registroCarros[i][col[j]];
        }
    }

    
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);    
}
```

**NOTE**
This JS code must be in your blade file otherwise you have to put exact URL in fetch, like: `fetch('xyz.com/returnJSON')`

---

Also verify if the controller & model is working fine and you're gettting proper data. You can do it in:

either Controller:

```
public function returnJSON()
{
    $teste = new user();
    $data = $teste->dbtest();
    dd($data);    // HERE

    return response()->json($data);    
}
```

or JS (in beginning of 'CreateTableFromJSON' function):

```
function CreateTableFromJSON(registroCarros = []) {
    console.log(registroCarros);    // HERE

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
fetch('{{ route('returnJSON') }}')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then( data => CreateTableFromJSON(data))
```

And remove the empty array inside the function

```
function CreateTableFromJSON(registroCarros) {
  //var registroCarros = [] remove this line
```

Change route:

```
Route::get('returnJSON', 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller@returnJSON')->name('returnJSON');
```

Comment: I think this will solve your problem. @Dan

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand your code properly, the missing piece is just the question how you *fetch* remote data. This is how you do it:

```js
fetch('returnJSON')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(CreateTableFromJSON)

function CreateTableFromJSON(registroCarros) {
    // ...
```

Comment: i will try it right now,but i just got a little bit confused. Where did you put 
"fetch('returnJSON')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(CreateTableFromJSON)"
is this in the controller?

Comment: No problem, this has to be in your JS Code

Comment: Thanks,but this is still not working. Absolutely nothing happens,my table is not even generated. Probably because it can't find the variable to generate it

Comment: Have you removed the line `registroCarros = []`?

Comment: Yes,i did. Does the "fetch('returnJSON')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(CreateTableFromJSON)" goes outside the function 'CreateTableFromJSON'?

Comment: Yes, it does. Otherwise the function would call itself which would result in an infinite loop

Comment: I get it. Well,sadly,still not working. I can't seem to get the route. Because everything else works,if i literally copy any json and put it as value of 'registroCarros', it works like a charm

Comment: Try `console.log()` on what is passed to `CreateTableFromJSON()`